# Implements of generate report for extension in gpedit snapin

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mmc

I have extension for the "Group Policy Editor" SnapIn (Computer/User configuration).

How can I implement of generate report in the "Settings" tab in gpmc for my extension?

Thanks.

Code.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.ManagementConsole;
using Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Advanced;

[assembly: PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, Unrestricted = true)]

namespace Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Samples
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class InstallUtilSupport : SnapInInstaller
    {}

    [SnapInSettings("0F3F3735-573D-9804-99E4-AB2A69BA5FD4", 
        DisplayName = "- Extension to Extensible SnapIn", 
        Description = "Sample showing how to extend a node.")]
    [ExtendsNodeType("8FC0B737-A0E1-11D1-A7D3-0000F87571E3")]
    public class ExtensionToSnapIn : NamespaceExtension
    {
        public ExtensionToSnapIn ()
        {}
        protected override void OnInitialize()
        {
            ScopeNode scopeNode = new ScopeNode();
            scopeNode.DisplayName = "My extension";
            PrimaryNode.Children.Add(scopeNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to provide some additional detail so we can help (e.g how you're attempting to do this, code-samples, what you've tried, etc.)

Comment: For write the extension I used sample from Windows SDK 7 (ExtensionToSnapInSample) and all works well. But I don't know how implement generation of report for my extension.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about this, but hopefully the extra information will make it easier to others to help :)